# Estimating how processor frequency affects I/O performance

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, network-programming, io, low-level

I am doing research about **dedicated I/O software** that would run on consumer hardware. Essentially it boils down to saving huge data streams for later processing. Right now I am looking for a model to estimate performance factors on **x86**.

Take for example the new [Macbook Pro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BNHM0C):

> high-speed Thunderbolt I/O (input/output) technology delivers
>   an amazing 10 gigabits per second of transfer speeds in both
>   directions

`1.25 GB/s` sounds nice but most processors of the day are clocked around `2 Ghz`. Multiple cores make little difference as long as only one can be assigned per network channel.

So even if the software acts as a miniature operating system and limits itself to network/disk operations, the amount of data flowing to storage can't be greater than **`P / (2 * N)`**<sup>[1]</sup> chunks per second. Although this hints the rough performance limit, I feel it's far from adequate.

**What other considerations should one take estimating I/O performance in regards to processor frequency and other hardware specifics?** For simplicity's sake, assume here that storage performs instantly under all circumstances.

*[1] **P** - processor frequency; **N** - algorithm overhead*

Comment: You also need to remember that a lot of high speed data transfers are using DMA(Direct Memory Access) through a custom hardware interface

Comment: @Mark Hall - Good point, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardware limiting factors are probably the I/O bus performance, say [PCIe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCIE), and more recently, the [FSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontside_bus) clock-rates, since memory controllers are moving from [northbridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_%28computing%29) to the [CPUs themselves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access).

Then, of course, you have to figure out what sort of processing you need to do on the input, and how much work it is to produce the output. These, at least for conventional software running on a CPU, are dependent on the processor clock, but not only. Writing your code to take advantage of the hardware facilities like caches, instruction-level parallelism, etc. is still a black art but can give you an order of magnitude performance boost.

Basically what I'm ranting about is that not all software is created equal, and you probably want to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, harddisk controllers will decide the harddisk I/O performance, graphics cards will decide maximum resolution and refresh I/O performance, and so on. Don't really understand the question, the CPU is becoming less and less involved in these kinds of things (well, has been for the last 10 years).

I doubt the question will even have bearing on CPUs with integrated GPUs, since the buffer to be output to screen is in external memory sharing a bus with (again) a controller on the motherboard.

It's all buffered, so I can only see CPUs affecting file performance if you somehow force the hardware buffer size to something insanely puny. Edit: and I'm pretty sure Apple will prevent you from doing such things. ;)

For Thunderbolt specifically, it's more about what the minimum CPU model is, that supports the kinds of bus speeds required by the Thunderbolt chip set version that is in the machine in question.

Thunderbolt is a raw data traffic system and performance specs are potential maximums, hence all the asterisks in the Apple specs. I believe it will indeed alleviate bottlenecks and in general give lag-free intelligent data shuffling doing many things simultaneously.

The CPU will idle-wait a shorter time for needed data, but the processing speed of the data is the same. When playing or creating a movie, codec processing time will be the same, but you will still feel a boost/lack of lag because the data is there when it needs it. For the I/O, the bottleneck will become the read/write speed of your harddisk instead, and the CPU bottleneck (for file copy operations, likely at least some code in Finder) will stay the same.

In other words, only CPU-intensive tasks such as for example movie encoding will benefit significantly from a faster CPU, while the benefits of Thunderbolt vs. a mix of interfaces will boost machines with both slow and fast CPUs.

Comment: I am not aware of any network interfaces writing directly to disk. Even with DMA it takes a CPU and some software to read from RAM and write to disk. This is where CPU frequency, architecture and other factors come in. Any thoughts on those?

Comment: All true. However I was thinking more along the lines of a **dedicated system**. In other words no iOS, no graphics, no sound, no peripherals, no nothing. Just bare I/O (network and disk). What would the performance factors be in **that** case? Obviously a 64-bit processor has **higher** data throughput per second than 32-bit since the former operates on longer data chunks. Etc. I'd like to reserve HDD issues for a separate question and assume here that storage performs instantly under all circumstances.